# What is "Overscoped for Position"?

Tags: canada

Got laid off and in the paperwork that I got from employer it states Overscoped for Position, what does that mean? I tried Googling but nothing like this comes up.

Comment: I guess some HR drone decided it sounded better than saying that you were overqualified and they reckoned they could find an intern to do it for a quarter of the pay. You could always just ask them as well. This seems like a company-specific question.

Comment: I agree. *We needed someone to physically move boxes but hired a supply chain engineer*, which is sort of like moving boxes beyond the scope of *physically* moving boxes, basically boils down to an overqualified hire where they can find a box mover for less money.

Comment: For me, "position was overscoped" makes sense. Saying a person was overscoped makes no sense.

Comment: "Thank you for your application, we will keep it on file in case it matches any other post we advertise" is 20 words when NO will do...

Comment: I think you need to get some advice from a Canadian labor lawyer here

Comment: @Fattie: So what does "position was overscoped" mean? Overscoped is not a word in the English language.

Comment: @gnasher729 Based on "overfed", "overworked", etc., a reasonable assumption would be that "overscoped" means something which was given too much scope. This makes sense for a position, but less so for a person.

Comment: @gnasher729 , "overscoped" is a very common "business English" word.  It's completely stupid and ridiculous - but (unfortunately!) it is commonly used.

Comment: @Dukeling Guessing the meaning of words makes no sense. The word is not in the dictionary.

Comment: I suspect this means they hired n people for a position but only needed n-m. It is a nicer way of saying “surplus to requirements”

Comment: @Gaius Exactly. You suspect. I don't know the word. I don't suspect anything when I don't know a word (in an important document), I say that I don't know the word.

Answer (score 2):

I'd call the employer and tell them that I have no idea what "overscoped for position" means, and that they please should change this sentence to correct English.

I have never seen the word "overscoped", the dictionary app on my Mac doesn't know the word, and Google doesn't know it either.